# How i can make a code in dialogflow that open the camera and take a picture?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

i'm new in  the chat bot programming . I would like to do exactly the command "ok google, take a picture", that the android open the camera and in 3 second take the pic. Dialogflow is a service from google, so  I thinking that there  are some library with some example of this, or if not, how I  need to search to put this command in my action ?

PS: I'm making a location and opinion action that receive from the user the place and the opinion about the place, so i would like to ask if the user want to take a pic from the place using this, but a don't know how a search this!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is currently no library and no direct support for this type of thing. The Assistant does not give Action developers access to the camera. In fact, most of the work your Action does is on a cloud-based server, not on the device itself.

You can, in some cases, use something like the [Android Link helper](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/helpers#android_link), but this requires the user to have installed your app on their phone, and doesn't quite do what it sounds like you want.